# GridView is partially visible

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

following is my layout

```
ScrollView (FILL_PARENT, FILL_PARENT)
LinearLayout (FILL_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT)
LinearLayout (FILL_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT)
TextView (Choose your favourtie hotels)
LinearLayout (FILL_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT)
GridView (10 rows)
```

However, only 1 and half rows are visible with vertical scrollbar. How can I ensure that GridView is fully visible?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try working with weights:

```
ScrollView (FILL_PARENT, FILL_PARENT)
    LinearLayout (FILL_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT)
        LinearLayout (FILL_PARENT, 0dp, WEIGHT 1)
            TextView (Choose your favourtie hotels)
        LinearLayout (FILL_PARENT, 0dp, WEIGHT 1)
            GridView (10 rows)
```

Comment: thanks for you quick reply but weight doesn't seems to work. Its same.

Answer (score 0):

do not use `GridView,ListView, etc` inside a `ScrollView` as they have itself scrollable Views. just remove `ScrollView` it will shown properly.

Just use

```
LinearLayout (FILL_PARENT, FILL_PARENT, orientation="vertical")
        TextView (Choose your favourtie hotels)
        GridView (10 rows)
```

You can use

```
 LinearLayout (FILL_PARENT, FILL_PARENT, orientation="vertical")
        (Include any View, Set of Views)
        GridView (10 rows)
        After GridView you can't add any View.
```

but in [worst](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3496042/1436931) case if it is must to use `GridView` inside a `ScrolView`. Then you nead to set the height of `GridView` in your Java code. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3495908/1436931) of measuring the height of list view you can do same for `gridView`.

Comment: @Mohsin well its a kind of form and has other components as well in similar pattern LinearLayout [LinearLayout[TextView : Label], LinearLayout[EditText/GridView : Content]

Comment: @Mohsin  I am trying to make it work but getting NullPointerException on listItem.onMeasure(0,0)